# Checking two columns and grouping to validate entries

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have data sheet as below-

[image]

I am trying to check for values in column `Count of deletions` if it is empty or not a number to flag an error at an account level,

because there will be only one entry of `Count of deletions` which will be at the first row entry of `Account ID (unique)` as illustrated in the pic above.

I did this to just validate the column `Count of deletions`

```
function myFunction() {
  SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var Validation_sheet = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet.getRange(2,5,last_row).getValues();
  var Status_values = sheet.getRange(2,4,last_row).getValues();

  var result = isnumberorEmpty(values, Status_values);
  const Count_setvalue = Validation_sheet.getRange("A2");
  var errors_c = [];
  for (key in result){
    var check1 = result[key] == "empty";
    var check2 = result[key] == "Not a number";
    if(check1 == true || check2 == true){
      errors_c.push(key);  
    }
  }
  if (errors_c.length > 0){
    Count_setvalue.setValue("Row(s) " + errors_c.join(" and ") + " have  error");
  }
  else{
    Count_setvalue.setValue("No errors");
  }
}

function isnumberorEmpty(array, array1) {
  let result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
    if( array1[i] == "Completed"){
      let row = array[i];
      if (row[0] === "") {
        result[i+2] = "empty";
      } 
      else if (row[0] === "Ignored") {
        result[i+2] = "No error";
      } 
      else if (!isNaN(row[0])) {
        result[i+2] = "number";
      } 
      else {
        result[i+2] = "Not a number";
      }
    }
    else{
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The above checks for column `Count of deletions` and  validates only where corresponding rows in column `Status` has `Completed`.

The output will show me error for rows, 8 and 10-18,
[image]

but it should not as the values are entered at the account level.

However, there should be error for only `Account4` and `Account5`, meaning the error should be only for Row `16` and row `18` as below -
[image]

Comment: Try creating a [mcve] ... you will probably solve your own question.

Comment: What are `I have data sheet as below-` and `as illustrated in the pic above.`? I'm worried that you might have miscopied your provided sample images. How about this?

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike - san, i added the screenshot in the question

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do and EXACTLY what is your problem. The code is flawed-presumably there should be a function at the outset but this is missing; "SS" is not defined, nor "UT_m"; the purpose and function of "Validation Sheet" is not explained nor is any data provided for this sheet; also there is no example of how a successful result would appear. Would you please include ALL your code, provide sample data in the form of a Table (as well as the image already provided) and also provide an example of of a successful outcome (a screenshot would be OK).

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding an image. But, from your current question, I cannot still understand your question. I apologize for this. And, I agree with @Tedinoz 's comment. I would like to think of a solution by correctly understanding your question. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I am really sorry for the confusion, I have provided the full code and also put screenshots of observed o/p and expected o/p. Hope this gives clarity, Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your updated question, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your updated question, I thought that the reason for your current issue might be due to that you checked columns "D" and "E". In order to achieve `However, there should be error for only Account4 and Account5, meaning the error should be only for Row 16 and row 18 as below -`, how about checking the columns "A", "D" and "E"? In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

```js
function myFunction1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Process in the source sheet.
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:E" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  const { errors_c } = values.reduce((o, r, i) => {
    if (i == 0 || o.temp != r[0]) {
      o.temp = r[0];
      if (r[3] == "Completed" && !r[4]) {
        o.errors_c.push(i + 2);
      }
    }
    return o;
  }, { errors_c: [], temp: "" });

  // Process in the destination sheet.
  const dstRange = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A2");
  if (errors_c.length > 0) {
    dstRange.setValue("Row(s) " + errors_c.join(" and ") + " have error");
  } else {
    dstRange.setValue("No errors");
  }
}
```

- In this modification, the columns "A", "D" and "E" are checked.
- When this script is tested to your sample input Spreadsheet, `Row(s) 16 and 18 have error` is put to the cell "A2" of "Sheet2".

#### Sample script 2:

Although unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, if you want to check all values of column "D" for each "Account ID", how about the following sample script?

```js
function myFunctionc2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Process in the source sheet.
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:E" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  const obj = values.reduce((m, r, i) => m.set(r[0], m.has(r[0]) ? { v: [...m.get(r[0]).v, r[3]], i: m.get(r[0]).i } : { v: [r[3]], i: i + 2 }), new Map()).values();
  const errors_c = [...obj].reduce((ar, { v, i }) => {
    if (v.every(e => e == "Completed") && !values[i - 2][4]) {
      ar.push(i);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Process in the destination sheet.
  const dstRange = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A2");
  if (errors_c.length > 0) {
    dstRange.setValue("Row(s) " + errors_c.join(" and ") + " have error");
  } else {
    dstRange.setValue("No errors");
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)